# How do I access a method in another class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am a beginner in Ruby.

I have been building code inside a single class as I have been learning but now that class has become bloated with code that is not necessarily relevant to the class.

Here is an example:

```
Class Server
    def initialize(server, port)
        @con = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'services', 'password', 'services'
        @server = server
        @port = port
    end
    def send(s)
        @chat.send "#{s}\n", 0
    end
    def connect()
        puts @con.get_server_info
        @con.query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \
                    rooms")
end
```

Here the database parts starting `@con` are not necessarily related to `Server` so I am thinking that I should create a new class `Database` and put all database related methods inside this, but my question is once I have moved all database related methods out of `Server` and in to `Database` how do I access those methods within `Database` from `Server`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access instance methods, then you need to create an instance first:

```
database = Database.new
database.connect
```

There are also class methods, which can be called directly on the class:

```
class Database
  def self.connect
  end
end

Database.connect
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the connection is necessary for the whole system, you can set it in the main class and inherit it to other classes:

```
class Server
  def initialize(server, port)
    @con = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'services', 'password', 'services'
    @server = server
    @port = port
  end

  def connect()
    puts @con.get_server_info
    @con.query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \
                rooms")
  end
end

class MyClass < Server
  def send(s)
    @chat.send "#{s}\n", 0
  end
end
```

So, `MyClass` can access the methods set in the `Server`.

**OR**

You can write a `module` and include it in the class:

```
module Database
  ...
end

class Server
  include Database
  ...
end
```